# Javascript - Exibir quantidade

Tags: javascript

Meu código é o seguinte:

```js
function adicionar(){
  
   var tabela = document.getElementById('tabela');
   var tp = document.getElementById("pedido");
   tp = tp.options[tp.selectedIndex].textContent;
   var qtd = document.getElementById("qtd").value;
   
   var ped_id = document.body.querySelectorAll(".rowtabela").length;
   
   var novo_item = '<div class="rowtabela" id="'+ped_id+'">'
   +'<div class="item">'+qtd+'</div>'
   +'<div class="item">'+tp+'</div>'
   +'<div class="botao">'
   +'<button onclick="remover(this)">X</button>'
   +'</div></div>';
   
   tabela.innerHTML += novo_item;
   
}

function remover(e){
   e.parentNode.parentNode.outerHTML = '';
}


  function enivar() {
var end = document.getElementById('endereco').value
var nome = document.getElementById('nome').value
var fone = document.getElementById('fone').value
var tabela = document.getElementsByClassName('rowtabela')

var qtd = tabela[1].childNodes[1]


alert("Nome: " + nome + "\nFone: " + fone + "\nEndereço: " + end + "\n\nPedidos: " + qtd);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Faça seu pedido</h1>
  <form action="">
    <div class="content">
      <label for="">Nome: </label>
      <input id="nome" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <label for="">Fone: </label>
      <input id="fone" type="number">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <label for="">Endereço: </label>
      <textarea id='endereco' name="textarea" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="sanduiche">
      <label for="">Pedido</label>
      <select name="" id="pedido">
        <option value="n001">Pedido Doidao 001</option>
        <option value="n002">Pedido Doidao 002</option>
        <option value="n003">Pedido Doidao 003</option>
        <option value="n004">Pedido Doidao 004</option>
      </select>
      <label for="">Pão</label>
      <select name="" id="pao">
        <option value="pao1">Pão 1</option>
        <option value="pao2">Pão 2</option>
        <option value="pao3">Pão 3</option>
        <option value="pao4">Pão 4</option>
      </select>
      <label for="">Quantidade</label>
      <input id="qtd" type="number">
      <button onclick="adicionar()">Adicionar</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class="adicionados" id="tabela">
    <div class="rowtabela">
      <div class="item">
        <b>Quantidade</b>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <b>Sanduíche</b>
      </div>
      <div class="item">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rowtabela">
      <div class="item" metaval='20'>
        20
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Sanduíche Brabissimo
      </div>
      <div class="botao">
        <button id="botao" onclick="remover(this);">X</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rowtabela">
      <div class="item" value='20'>
        20
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Sanduíche Brabissimo
      </div>
      <div class="botao">
        <button id="botao" onclick="remover(this);">X</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rowtabela">
      <div value='20' class="item">
        20
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Sanduíche Brabissimo
      </div>
      <div class="botao">
        <button id="botao" onclick="remover(this);">X</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button onclick="enivar()" class="enviar">Enviar</button>
</div>
```

Gostaria de exibir a quantidade utilizando Javascript no `alert`

Comment: Qual a dificuldade? O que deveria fazer a função `adicionar`, que não foi definida?

Comment: Atualize o codigo com a função adicionar

Comment: Acabei de atualizar, eu gostaria de buscar os elementos inseridos dentro da div  tabela e exibi-los no alert

Answer (score 1):

> No seu código ao clicar no botão `Adicionar`o formulário está sendo enviado!

Para entender o porque, veja os tipos (type) de buttons abaixo e seu comportamento.

- O Elemento HTML `<button>` representa um botão clicável.

  - `submit`: como o proprio nome diz, submete os dados à URL especificada no action do FORM. **Esse é o padrão se o atributo não for especifidado**, ou se o atributo é dinamicamente mudado para um valor vazio ou inválido.
  - `reset`: restaura todos os elementos de entrada do formulário aos seus valores iniciais.
  - `button`: O botão não possui comportamento padrão. Ele pode ter scripts do lado do cliente associado com os eventos do elemento, no qual são acionados quando o evento ocorrer.

***1ª correção no código:***  `type="button"` no botão `Adicionar`

```
<button type="button" onclick="adicionar()">Adicionar</button>
```

***2ª correção*** - Para saber a quantidade de elementos com a classe `rowtabela`.

```
var tabela = document.getElementsByClassName('rowtabela')
var qtd = tabela.length;
```

> observe que há uma div com classe `rowtabela`

```
<div class="rowtabela">
  <div class="item">
    <b>Quantidade</b>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <b>Sanduíche</b>
  </div>
  <div class="item">

  </div>
</div>
```

> que também fará parte da contagem. Caso não deva ser contada, há que se diminuir uma unidade da `var qtd`, ou seja,  var `qtd = tabela.length - 1;`

**Veja exemplo funcionando**

```js
function adicionar(){
  
   var tabela = document.getElementById('tabela');
   var tp = document.getElementById("pedido");
   tp = tp.options[tp.selectedIndex].textContent;
   var qtd = document.getElementById("qtd").value;
   
   var ped_id = document.body.querySelectorAll(".rowtabela").length;
   
   var novo_item = '<div class="rowtabela" id="'+ped_id+'">'
   +'<div class="item">'+qtd+'</div>'
   +'<div class="item">'+tp+'</div>'
   +'<div class="botao">'
   +'<button onclick="remover(this)">X</button>'
   +'</div></div>';
   
   tabela.innerHTML += novo_item;
   
}

function remover(e){
   e.parentNode.parentNode.outerHTML = '';
}


function enivar() {
var end = document.getElementById('endereco').value
var nome = document.getElementById('nome').value
var fone = document.getElementById('fone').value
var tabela = document.getElementsByClassName('rowtabela')

//var qtd = tabela[1].childNodes[1]
var qtd = tabela.length;

alert("Nome: " + nome + "\nFone: " + fone + "\nEndereço: " + end + "\n\nPedidos: " + qtd);
}
```

```html
   <div class="container">
  <h1>Faça seu pedido</h1>
  <form action="">
<div class="content">
  <label for="">Nome: </label>
  <input id="nome" type="text">
</div>
<div class="content">
  <label for="">Fone: </label>
  <input id="fone" type="number">
</div>
<div class="content">
  <label for="">Endereço: </label>
  <textarea id='endereco' name="textarea" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="sanduiche">
  <label for="">Pedido</label>
  <select name="" id="pedido">
    <option value="n001">Pedido Doidao 001</option>
    <option value="n002">Pedido Doidao 002</option>
    <option value="n003">Pedido Doidao 003</option>
    <option value="n004">Pedido Doidao 004</option>
  </select>
  <label for="">Pão</label>
  <select name="" id="pao">
    <option value="pao1">Pão 1</option>
    <option value="pao2">Pão 2</option>
    <option value="pao3">Pão 3</option>
    <option value="pao4">Pão 4</option>
  </select>
  <label for="">Quantidade</label>
  <input id="qtd" type="number">
  <button type="button" onclick="adicionar()">Adicionar</button>
</div>
  </form>
  <div class="adicionados" id="tabela">
<div class="rowtabela">
  <div class="item">
    <b>Quantidade</b>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <b>Sanduíche</b>
  </div>
  <div class="item">

  </div>
</div>
<div class="rowtabela">
  <div class="item" metaval='20'>
    20
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Sanduíche Brabissimo
  </div>
  <div class="botao">
    <button id="botao" onclick="remover(this);">X</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="rowtabela">
  <div class="item" value='20'>
    20
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Sanduíche Brabissimo
  </div>
  <div class="botao">
    <button id="botao" onclick="remover(this);">X</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="rowtabela">
  <div value='20' class="item">
    20
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Sanduíche Brabissimo
  </div>
  <div class="botao">
    <button id="botao" onclick="remover(this);">X</button>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
  <button onclick="enivar()" class="enviar">Enviar</button>
</div>
```